# tcpdf table generated rows displayed not constant

Tags: php, mysql, tcpdf

I am trying to generate a table using tcpdf in codeigniter framework. The structure I am trying to generate is like below.

```
________________________________________________________
header 1
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
description 1 |    |     |     |     |     |     |     |
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯ 
header 2 
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
subheader 2.1
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
description 2.1.1
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
description 2.1.2
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
subheader 2.2
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
description 2.2.1
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
header 3
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
description 3.1
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
description 3.2
```

While I am able to get the above table, however, the table generated is not constant. Sometimes it gives me all rows and cells except description 3.1 and description 3.2. I tried the mysql query and it generates the expected result every time. My code is:

```
function createPDF($chklistID){

    $this->load->library("Pdf");
    $title="Daily Checklist Template";
    $subject="Daily Checklist";
    $author = "Derek Lim";
    // create new PDF document
    $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);    

    // set document information
    $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
    $pdf->SetAuthor($author);
    $pdf->SetTitle($title);
    $pdf->SetSubject($subject);
    //$pdf->SetKeywords('');   

    // set default header data
    $pdf->setHeaderFont(array('', '', 20));
    $pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE, PDF_HEADER_STRING, array(0,64,255), array(0,64,128));
    $pdf->setFooterData(array(0,64,0), array(0,64,128)); 

    // set header and footer fonts
    $pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
    $pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));  

    // set default monospaced font
    $pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED); 

    // set margins
    $pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
    $pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
    $pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);    

    // set auto page breaks
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM); 

    // set image scale factor
    $pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);  

    // set some language-dependent strings (optional)
    if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {
        require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
        $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
    }   

    // ---------------------------------------------------------    

    // set default font subsetting mode
    $pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);   

    // Set font
    // dejavusans is a UTF-8 Unicode font, if you only need to
    // print standard ASCII chars, you can use core fonts like
    // helvetica or times to reduce file size.
    $pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 11, '', true);   

    // Add a page
    // This method has several options, check the source code documentation for more information.
    $pdf->AddPage(); 

    // set text shadow effect
    $pdf->setTextShadow(array('enabled'=>true, 'depth_w'=>0.2, 'depth_h'=>0.2, 'color'=>array(196,196,196), 'opacity'=>1, 'blend_mode'=>'Normal'));
    // Set some content to print
    $html = '<div width="100%"><br/><br/><table><tr><td width="20%"><b>Project:</b></td><td width="80%">_______________________________________________</td></tr></div>';

    //get worklist type name
    $worklistName = $this->checklists_model->get_worklist($chklistID);

    //gen html
    $html = $this->gen_html($chklistID);        

    // Print text using writeHTMLCell()
    $pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 0, '', '', $html, 0, 1, 0, true, '', true);   

    // ---------------------------------------------------------    

    // Close and output PDF document
    // This method has several options, check the source code documentation for more information.
    $chklistPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."safety/checklists/";
    $pdf->Output($chklistPath.urlencode($worklistName->checklistName).'.pdf', 'F'); //save to file
    $pdf->Output(urlencode($worklistName->checklistName).'.pdf', 'I'); //preview in screen
}

function gen_html($chklistID){
    //get worklist type name
    $worklistName = $this->checklists_model->get_worklist($chklistID);
    $html .= '<div width="100%" style="text-align:center;"><b>'.$worklistName->checklistName.' Checklist</b></div>';
    $html .= '<div width="100%" ><table><tr><td width="30%"><b>Contractor:</b></td><td width="70%">_______________________________________________</td></tr><tr><td></td></tr><tr><td width="30%"><b>Location/Area:</b></td><td width="70%">_______________________________________________</td></tr><tr><td></td></tr><tr><td width="30%"><b>Date of Inpection:</b></td><td width="70%">_________________________ To ______________________</td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><td width="30%"><b>Location/Area:</b></td><td width="70%">_______________________________________________</td></tr><tr><td></td></tr><tr><td width="30%"><b>Inspected/Checked by:</b></td><td width="70%" style="text-align:center;">_______________________________________________<br/>(Name &amp; Signature)</td></tr></table></div>';

    $html .= '<div><table border="1"><tr><th width="7%" style="text-align:center;">S/No</th><th width="40%" style="text-align:center;">Description</th><th width="50%" style="text-align:center;">Day<br/><table border="1"><tr><th>Mon</th><th>Tue</th><th>Wed</th><th>Thu</th><th>Fri</th><th>Sat</th><th>Sun</th></tr></table></th></tr>';
    $headers = $this->checklists_model->get_headers($chklistID);
    $sn = 1;
    foreach ($headers as $header) {
        if($header->chklistDailyConditionsCatParent==0){
            $conditions = $this->checklists_model->get_conditions($header->chklistDailyConditionsCatID);
            $html .= '<tr><td></td><td><u>'.$header->chklistDailyConditionsCatName.'</u></td><td></td></tr>';
            foreach ($conditions as $condition) {
                $html .= '<tr><td>'.$sn.'</td><td>'.$condition->chklistConditionsName.'</td><td><table border="1" style="width:100%;"><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></table></td></tr>';
                $sn++;
            }
            $sn1 = $sn;
        }elseif($header->chklistDailyConditionsCatParent!=0){
            $subConditions = $this->checklists_model->get_subConditions($header->chklistDailyConditionsCatID);
            $html .= '<tr><td></td><td> -<u>'.$header->chklistDailyConditionsCatName.'</u></td><td></td></tr>';
            foreach ($subConditions as $condition) {
                $html .= '<tr><td>'.$sn1.'</td><td>&nbsp; '.$condition->chklistConditionsName.'</td><td><table border="1" style="width:100%;"><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></table></td></tr>';
                $sn1++;
            }
            $sn = $sn1;
        }
    }
    $html .= '<tr><td></td><td>Signature:</td><td><table border="1" style="width:100%;"><tr><td style="height:100px;"></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></table></td></tr>';
    $html .= '</table></div>';

    $html .= '<div><span><h4>Legend:</h4><br/><br/>X No/Not Satisfactory<br/><br/>&#10004; Yes/Good<br/><br/>C Not Applicable</span></div>';
    $html .= '<div><h4>Remarks:</h4></div>';
    return $html;
}
```

Is there anything I did wrongly?

Answer (score 0):

try to use this code working for me . you have to crate a file in helpers folder pdf_helper.php and write this code and also place tcpdf library folder in this folder

```
    <?php

function tcpdf()
{
    //require_once('tcpdf/config/lang/eng.php');
    require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
}


?>
```

in your view page write this code

```
 <?php get_instance()->load->helper('pdf_helper');  
            tcpdf();
            $obj_pdf = new TCPDF('P', PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
            $obj_pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
            $title = "PDF Report";
            $obj_pdf->SetTitle($title);
            $obj_pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, $title, PDF_HEADER_STRING);
            $obj_pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
            $obj_pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));
            $obj_pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont('helvetica');
            $obj_pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
            $obj_pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);
            $obj_pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
            $obj_pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);
            $obj_pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 9);
            $obj_pdf->setFontSubsetting(false);

           $obj_pdf->SetPrintHeader(false);
           $obj_pdf->SetPrintFooter(false);
           $obj_pdf->AddPage();
            ob_start();
            ?>

           <html>write your html here .....</html>

       <?php
        $content = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        $obj_pdf->writeHTML($content, true, false, true, false, '');
    //$obj_pdf->Output('output.pdf', 'I');
        $obj_pdf->Output($this->config->item('server_absolute_path').'/application/controllers/invoice_pdf/Invoice_'.$booking_details[0]['id'].'.pdf', 'F'); ?>
```

a file with name invoice.pdf will save in controllers folder